# Were the Peverell brothers and Salazar Slytherin related?

Tags: harry-potter, genealogy, slytherin

Were the Peverell brothers and Slytherin related or not?  In the books it is mentioned that both were ancestors of Voldemort, but I couldn't find their mutual relation.

Comment: According to the Harry Potter Wikia (which may not be a perfect source) they aren't related, but the Brothers' line and Slytherin's joined at the House of Gaunt http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Peverell_family

Comment: Wiki doesn't say something about their ancestors..

Comment: No, but it suggests that the families are unconnected until that point, as do other trees (http://i7.photobucket.com/albums/y260/theGodslayer/peverell.jpg, for example). But you're right, it doesn't say that they're NOT related before Gaunt either, which is why I only added it as a comment that may nudge someone towards the right answer.

Comment: Given how typical nobility lines worked, everyone was pretty much related to everyone

Answer (score 6):

It's confirmed that the families are united through Marvolo Gaunt. He is explicitly referred to in the book as a direct descendant of Salazar Slytherin. It is also explicitly stated that the Gaunts trace their lineage to Cadmus Peverell.

Because we know both NAMES died (lineage extinct in the male line, but not dead) and because the Gaunt family is the uniting factor, it can be reasonably deduced that Cadmus Peverell and Salazar Slytherin were not directly related in their own time, but that their descendants intermarried.

The short answer: no.