# Did Salazar Slytherin know the stone in his ring was the Resurrection Stone?

Tags: harry-potter

Did Salazar Slytherin know the stone in his ring was the Resurrection Stone? Or was he unaware of it's significance or just came across the stone by happenstance? In the 'tale' the second brother kills himself and it isn't mentioned whether he told others about what his stone unlike the oldest brother who boasted about the wand.

Comment: Related question is http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/119881/4918 "Who came first; The Four Founders or the Peverell Brothers?".

Comment: I don't think that is related. The asker specifically asks if *did he know* not *who came first*. There's a big difference.

Comment: @BookStriker That's why it's _related_, and not a duplicate.

Comment: @krillgar I just don't think it's related at all.

Comment: I don't know the books well, but this showed up in my Hot Questions feed. Is it a spoiler to know that it is the Resurrection Stone?

Comment: @Almo maybe. it is a stone that makes more-than-ghosts of your friends/relatives/loved ones appear.

Comment: It would be nice if it is a spoiler if we could change the title.

Comment: @MarkGardner Lol. "It's not exactly a spoiler, but here's a more in-depth spoiler" :P

Comment: I actually originally titled it "Salazar Slytherin's ring?" someone else changed it to what it is now. I'm new to the site and find my questions are never right and always edited; Ive either too much or too little detail in them.

Comment: Yes, we generally edit questions to have more descriptive titles.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## The ring never belonged to Slytherin

Gaunt only claims the locket is Slytherins, not the ring. He claims the ring as belonging to the Peverells - aka the Brothers from the story.

> "That's right!" roared
>   Gaunt. For a moment, Harry thought Gaunt was making an obscene hand
>   gesture, but then realized that **he was showing Ogden the ugly,
>   black-stoned ring he was wearing on his middle finger, waving it
>   before Ogden's eyes.**
>
> "See this? See this? Know what it is? Know where
>   it came from? Centuries it's been in our family, that's how far back
>   we go, and pure-blood all the way! **Know how much I've been offered for
>   this, with the Peverell coat of arms engraved on the stone?**"
>
> [...]
>
> With a howl of rage, Gaunt ran toward his
>   daughter. For a split second, Harry thought he was going to throttle
>   her as his hand flew to her throat; next moment, **he was dragging her
>   toward Ogden by a gold chain around her neck.**
>
> "See this?" he bellowed
>   at Ogden,**shaking a heavy gold locket at him**,while Merope spluttered
>   and gasped for breath.
>
> "I see it, I see it!" said Ogden hastily.
>
> **"Slytherins!" yelled Gaunt. "Salazar Slytherin's! We're his last
>   living descendants, what do you say to that, eh?"**

In addtition, as @b_jonas points out, [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/119881/4918) establishes that the Peverells came after The Founders of Hogwarts. Even if he did claim the ring was Slytherins I'd be wary of believing him - he was right about the locket but the pure blood families have a tendency to make up or exaggerate their claims to ancient ancestry. As Harry says

> "Marvolo Gaunt was an ignorant old git who lived like a pig, all he
>   cared about was his ancestry. If that ring had been passed down
>   through the centuries, he might not have known what it really was.
>   There were no books in that house, and trust me, he wasn’t the type to
>   read fairy tales to his kids. **He’d have loved to think the scratches
>   on the stone were a coat of arms, because as far as he was concerned,
>   having pure blood made you practically royal**."

Or how about another example from our favourite monster?

> "That’s - that’s pretty, Dolores," she said, pointing at the pendant
>   gleaming in the ruffled folds of Umbridge’s blouse.
>
> "What?" snapped
>   Umbridge, glancing down. "**Oh yes - an old family heirloom," she said,
>   patting the locket lying on her large bosom. "The S stands for
>   Selwyn.... I am related to the Selwyns.... Indeed, there are few
>   pure-blood families to whom I am not related**".

Comment: @TheDarkLord Did I do a dumb?

Comment: No, it just amused me as form of ellipsis. :)

Comment: "Indeed, there are few pure-blood families to whom I am not related." That is generally not something to be proud of... lol

Comment: @jpmc26 On the contrary I think someone interested in racial inheritance and pureblood superiority, being connected in some way to others of your 'superior bloodline' would be a badge of honor. Umbridge was one such person who was always looking for badges of honor to make herself feel more superior.

Comment: So the "snip" is being used as an ellipsis right? At first I thought his daughter cut off his finger and ran away with the ring....

Comment: As far as I was aware "snip" is a pretty common term used on this site to indicate useless text being removed. Have I made this up by myself? :P

Comment: @DavidS I don't know if I've seen much on this site in particular, but I've seen it every once and a while in various contexts, so I'd say it's valid, even if uncommon.

Comment: @TylerH It implies inbreeding. =p Yes, I get there are people who are sick enough to consider it an honor.

Comment: @DavidS Yes, it's common on this site. Although in writing, the ellipsis is the standard way of indicating that a portion of the quote was omitted. If you're going to use "snip," I'd at least put it in square braces to clarify that it's something you inserted (e.g. "[snip]").

Comment: @jpmc26 Meh, all organisms are inbred if you go back far enough :-P

Comment: I found the "_snip_" confusing. How is the reader to know that italics are special, and not part of the quote? I'm a big fan of "**[...]**" (or "**[…]**", same with an ellipsis character instead of 3 period characters). Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55820/how-would-you-properly-show-deletion-of-unnecessary-text-in-a-quote . Loosely related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90161/where-does-emphasis-mine-go-in-a-quotation