# Did the Peverell brothers attend Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

Related to my own question: [Who came first; The Four Founders or the Peverell Brothers?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119881/who-came-first-the-four-founders-or-the-peverell-brothers)

The current answer is that Hogwarts was founded in 993 AD and the oldest Peverell (Ignotus) was born in 1214 AD.

So as such, **is there any evidence the brothers attended Hogwarts?**

Comment: I'll bet JKR has said something on this at some point. If not, you could tweet her. She loves to make up things on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## We don't know.

There is **no** canon info on this (at least that I could find).

I would assume that they went to *some* wizarding school, **probably** Hogwarts, as

- The Gaunts live in Britian
- The Gaunts are descended from the Peverells (probably the middle brother)

so

- We can assume that the Peverells lived in Britian.

Also, Ignotus's grave was in Godric's Hallow, so that's additional proof that they were British.

Comment: I guess that raises another question even before we get to this one... I always thought of the Tales of Beedle the Bard to be a parallel to the Brothers Grimm/Mother Goose.  Their stories are common and popular all over the world but their origin is usually Germanic. Just because the stories are popular with English wizards does not mean the Peverells were British... Their lineage suggests that, but the family could have moved at any point.

Comment: @Skooba True, but until evidence proves otherwise, I'll assume that they're British.

Answer (score 0):

The three brothers were born after Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry was founded. They are related to Slytherin by marriage (their descendants married) but that does not indicate they actually attended the school.

Ignotus Peverell and his brothers were knowledgable in magical arts but there is no actual proof whether the Peverell brothers attended Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry, were home-schooled or learned about the magical arts on their own, autodidactically.

I'd ask J.K. Rowling. You might get lucky?

Comment: What is your source for the Peverells being related to Slytherin? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53486/were-the-peverell-brothers-and-salazar-slytherin-related/74185#74185 -- most sources tend to think that the Gaunts are convergence point for Voldy to to be related to both.

Comment: He said "their descendants married" so that's what he meant even if a lot of people wouldn't consider that actually being related.